# Are there any consequences of clicking on a URL to a facebook.com link?

Tags: windows, chrome, facebook, url-redirection

So I stupidly clicked on a suspicious link on a Facebook post today. Guest account for shame. In my defense, it was a link to facebook.com itself, but it loaded a Facebook page, then seemed to redirect. I closed my browser less than a second after. I cleared all local browser data, changed my password, made sure no browser addons or Facebook apps were added, and ran a virus scan. Everything seems okay. Did I miss anything? Reformatting my PC or changing other site passwords is overkill, right? This was in Chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: ` Reformatting my PC or changing other site passwords is overkill, right?` Certainly not. If anything, that's underkill. My professional recommendation would be to abandon all technology and flee to the hilly woodlands, thereby subsisting on nuts and berries until this whole thing blows over. It might take a year, might take a decade. Bring no supplies with you, and tell no friends or relatives where you're going. Remember: they have spies everywhere, and nowhere is safe.

Answer (score 1):

In **theory**, you could have caught a **drive by download**. However, it is much more likely that you have been redirected to an **advertisement page** and the respective owner now rejoices about the revenue of all the sheeps clicking on funny looking links ;-)

You can delete your cookies to get rid of any tracking/advertisement ones and I generally recommend installing a third party script, frame and cookie blocker. Also I hope you are not browsing with an administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use share me not and Adblocker plugins

The link might be just an AD or also can be clickjacking page or phishing page.

Visiting that link might trigger a download of malicious file( some people put default action as download). Better not to click such links